# R igraph edgelist to adjacency matrix How to trim 0 chunks?

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I have an edge list with 3 columns, akin to From, To, Weight, but it has no row/column names.

```
A1    B1    0.3
A1    B2    0.2
A1    B3    0.1
A2    B1    0.3
A2    B2    0.2
A2    B3    0.3
...   ...
```

Further detail: Col 1 ONLY has "Ax", and col 2 only has "Bx", they are meant to be different types. There will never be a true cross within Ax nor within Bx, e.g. there will never be a row like

```
A1    A3    0.2
```

Also, the resulting adjacency matrix is expected to be perfectly square, there are exactly as many A as there are B, and every A maps exactly once to every B, and vice versa.

Following other stackoverflow threads, I have applied

```
library(igraph)    
gdf <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
adj_mat <- get.adjacency(gdf, sparse = FALSE, attr='X3')
```

However, this output is full of Ax-Ax and Bx-Bx pairs, i.e.

```
     A1    A2    A3
A1   0     0     0
A2   0     0     0
A3   0     0     0
```

before moving on to (also this is my desired result, without the leading and trailing chunks of 0s)

```
...  A1    A2    A3
B1   0.3   0.3   ...
B2   0.2   0.2   ...
B3   0.1   0.3   ...
```

Followed by a big square chunk of 0s with Bx-Bx crosses.

So this matrix is about 3x as big as it needs to be.

My ACTUAL adj_mat output in R, in case this helps:

```
                  query_0 query_1 query_2 query_3 query_4 query_5 query_6 query_7 reference_B reference_CD4_T
query_0                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.9211076       0.9357135
query_1                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.5982098       0.6531529
query_2                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.9414440       0.9163261
query_3                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.7776452       0.7595893
query_4                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.1742785       0.4535070
query_5                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.8929904       0.8692392
query_6                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.8727388       0.9143452
query_7                 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.6672841       0.7709745
reference_B             0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_CD4_T         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_CD8_T         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_DC            0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_Mono          0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_NK            0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_other         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
reference_other_T       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   0.0000000       0.0000000
                  reference_CD8_T reference_DC reference_Mono reference_NK reference_other reference_other_T
query_0                 0.9795670    0.9616339      0.2036382    0.9735171       0.9868448         0.9683900
query_1                 0.9581395    0.9263749      0.8985018    0.8132070       0.7481512         0.9580464
query_2                 0.4993608    0.3923397      0.9837582    0.9125077       0.9859413         0.9322740
query_3                 0.9069418    0.8334141      0.9652273    0.1926747       0.9856065         0.9556887
query_4                 0.9415359    0.8987213      0.9075660    0.7965302       0.9804007         0.9542930
query_5                 0.3971887    0.5269301      0.9410492    0.9178430       0.9854246         0.6326137
query_6                 0.9752365    0.9528309      0.9084781    0.9701409       0.9274201         0.9644051
query_7                 0.9712323    0.9535511      0.9000940    0.9376305       0.8200538         0.9356329
reference_B             0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_CD4_T         0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_CD8_T         0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_DC            0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_Mono          0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_NK            0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_other         0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
reference_other_T       0.0000000    0.0000000      0.0000000    0.0000000       0.0000000         0.0000000
```

In this particular case, I can get to the result I want with

```
adj_mat<- adj_mat[, -c(1:8)]
adj_mat<- adj_mat[-c(9:16),]
```

But I'm hoping to find something more generalized.

I don't strictly have to use `igraph` package, I'm open to using any other packages to convert from the edge list to the adjacency matrix, or even just magic data wrangling.

Comment: Do you want to reshape the data? `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = From, values_from = Weight)`. Also see various options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `xtabs`

```
> xtabs(Weight ~ ., df)
    To
From  B1  B2  B3
  A1 0.3 0.2 0.1
  A2 0.3 0.2 0.3
```

or

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Weight ~ ., df))
    B1  B2  B3
A1 0.3 0.2 0.1
A2 0.3 0.2 0.3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(From = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2"), 
    To = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B1", "B2", "B3"), Weight = c(0.3,
    0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```